# Using time_bucket and joining multiple tables in timescaledb

Tags: timescaledb

I have a simple database schema (Timescaledb) with a few tables. Each user has one main sensor with multiple metrics, each metric has its own table with user_id and timestamp.

**Schema**

```
Table 1
```

| user_id | timestamp | val1 | val...
|:---- |:------:| -----:| -----:
Table ...

| user_id | timestamp | val1 | val... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

**Question**

I want to know how can I merge these tables in a view with the `time_bucket` function. So, if I sample it every 10 seconds to show something like
View

| user_id | timestamp | agg val from table 1 | agg val from table 2 | agg val from table X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! it's possible!

You can try it by using regular SQL. Here is some example:

```sql
select time_bucket('1m', a.time) as bucket_a,
          a.symbol || '/' || b.symbol as pair,
          LAST(a.price, a.time) as last_price_a,
          LAST(b.price, b.time) as last_price_b
          FROM ticks a
          LEFT JOIN ticks b
          ON time_bucket('1m', a.time) = time_bucket('1m', b.time)
            AND a.symbol = 'SYMBOL' and b.symbol = 'ANOTHER'
          GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Note that I'm joining the table `ticks` twice, you can just join another table with the other metrics.

Another detail is that instead of filtering the `symbol` on where clause, it's now part of the `JOIN` clause.

Comment: Thank you @jonatasdp I think that worked. 

My query:

SELECT t1.user_id, time_bucket('10 seconds',
    t1.timestamp) as timestamp_bucket,
      LAST(t1.accuracy, t1.timestamp) as last_acc,
       LAST(t2.status, t2.timestamp) as last_status
FROM tabble1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
       time_bucket('10 seconds', t1.timestamp) = time_bucket('10 seconds', t2.timestamp)
WHERE t1.user_id = 'user_X'
GROUP BY t1.user_id, timestamp_bucket, t2.timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp_bucket;

Comment: However that solves it for two tables, what if I have 20 tables with the same users in each table? Is it still scalable to write a join for 20 tables and 20 `time_buckets`? Also what does last as an aggregator with time bucket does exactly? My understanding is that it's only gonna get the last value in the aggregation, is that correct?

Comment: @JeanToniolli take a look at the FILTER option: https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/how-to-use-the-filter-clause-in-postgresql-881